# Recaptcha v2 не грузится

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, recaptcha

У меня на странице (веб-приложение написано на ASP.NET MCV5) две формы, обе защищены recaptcha v2. Капчи я рендерю самостоятельно (explicit).

```
<script src="//www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=CaptchaCallback&render=explicit"
 async defer></script>
```

С тех пор как мы решили отказаться от автоматического рендера, начались проблемы: сама капча загружается только на 3-4 раз.

Как это выглядит в HTML:

```
 <div id="captchaCredits"></div>
 <input type="text" id="captchaCredInput" name="captchaCredInput"
 style="display:none" disabled ="disabled">
```

(input нужен для одной хитрости с валидацией всей формы)

Функция для рендера:

```
 var CaptchaCallback = function(){
    var mail = grecaptcha.render('captchaCredits', { 'sitekey': '...', 'theme': 'light'});
}
```

Как можно оставить на странице обе капчи, но добиться того, чтобы они прогружались каждый раз?

**UPD**: комментирование одной из капч на странице не помогает. Добавление же `console.log(123)` в `CaptchaCallback` показало, что эта функция может вообще при загрузке не вызываться.

Comment: Не совсем понятно что именно послужило проблемой, explicit рендеринг или то что капчи на странице две. Что, кстати, странно, не могли вы пояснить необходимость этого?

Comment: Да, я сейчас попробую одну убрать, спасибо за идею.


Страница предназначена для записи на обучение. В первую форму пользователь вводит свои данные, если хочет прослушать курс (и понятно, что тут мы не хотим разбираться со спам-заявками), а вторая -- просто подписка на обновления, но в ТЗ сказано, что эта форма тоже должна быть защищена капчей.

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно было просто перенести загрузку всех нужных мне библиотек в `<head>`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-ui-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/expromptum.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=CaptchaCallback&render=explicit" async defer></script>
```

И всё, скрипт, вызывающий загрузку капчи, работает каждый раз.